# Python Tornado Async Fetching of URLs

Tags: python, concurrency, tornado

In the following code example I have a function `do_async_thing` which appears to return a `Future`, even though I'm not sure why?

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpclient

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def do_async_thing():
    http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http.fetch("http://www.google.com/")
    return response.body

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        x = do_async_thing()
        print(x) # <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x10753a6a0>

        self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        self.write('{"foo":"bar"}')
        self.finish()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/foo/?", MainHandler),
    ])
    app.listen(8888)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

You'll see that I `yield` the call to `fetch` and in doing so I should have forced the value to be *realised* (and subsequently been able to access the `body` field of the response).

What's more interesting is how I can even access the `body` field on a Future and not have it error (as far as I know a Future has no such field/property/method)

So does anyone know how I can:

1. Resolve the Future so I get the actual value
2. Modify this example so the function `do_async_thing` makes multiple async url fetches

Now it's worth noting that because I was still getting a Future back I thought I would try adding a `yield` to prefix the call to `do_async_thing()` (e.g. `x = yield do_async_thing()`) but that gave me back the following error:

```
tornado.gen.BadYieldError: yielded unknown object <generator object get at 0x1023bc308>
```

I also looked at doing something like this for the second point:

```
def do_another_async_thing():
    http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    a = http.fetch("http://www.google.com/")
    b = http.fetch("http://www.github.com/")
    return a, b

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        y = do_another_async_thing()
        print(y)
```

But again this returns:

```
<tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x102b966d8>
```

Where as I would've expected a tuple of Futures at least? At this point I'm unable to resolve these Futures without getting an error such as:

```
tornado.gen.BadYieldError: yielded unknown object <generator object get at 0x1091ac360>
```

### Update

Below is an example that works (as per answered by A. Jesse Jiryu Davis)

But I've also added another example where by I have a new function `do_another_async_thing` which makes *two* async HTTP requests (but evaluating their values are a little bit more involved as you'll see):

```
def do_another_async_thing():
    http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    a = http.fetch("http://www.google.com/")
    b = http.fetch("http://www.github.com/")
    return a, b

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def do_async_thing():
    http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http.fetch("http://www.google.com/")
    return response.body

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        x = yield do_async_thing()
        print(x) # displays HTML response

        fa, fb = do_another_async_thing()
        fa = yield fa
        fb = yield fb
        print(fa.body, fb.body) # displays HTML response for each
```

It's worth clarifying: you might expect the two `yield` statements for `do_another_async_thing` to cause a blockage. But here is a breakdown of the steps that are happening:

- `do_another_async_thing` returns immediately a tuple with two Futures
- we `yield` the first tuple which causes the program to be blocked until the value is realised
- the value is realised and so we move to the next line
- we `yield` again, causing the program to block until the value is realised
- but as both futures were created at the same time and run concurrently the second `yield` returns practically instantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coroutines return futures. To wait for the coroutine to complete, the caller must *also* be a coroutine, and must yield the future. So:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    x = yield do_async_thing()
```

For more info see [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).

Comment: Thanks, that appears to work. How would you structure the code so that `do_async_thing` actually made two separate calls to `http.fetch`? I assume because `yield` forces the value to be evaluated, then you couldn't do what I'm asking without negating the async performance. Instead maybe you'd have another function marked with `@tornado.gen.coroutine` that async fetched the other url? Or maybe you not yield the multiple fetches and instead yielded a tuple at the end of the function; but then at some point `get(self)` would need to `yield` twice (once for each Future returned within the tuple)

Comment: The article I linked also answers that exact question.